# ZPL Variable Width

Tags: c#, printing, zpl

I have to print a label with a variable amount of fields that have a set size.

For example, the label might include Product Number (size 1), Description (size 7), Ship Date (size 3), Price (size 2).

The sizes are relative. How can I set the width of each field? ^FOx,y defines where on the x-axis the the field is. If a field with a smaller size precedes a field with a larger size how can I set the origin appropriately?

Comment: What size? Height? Width? Characters? Please add an example?

Comment: If I understand correctly from your question, you want the fields to concatenate together.(?)  Read up on the `^FT` command.  It is similar to `^FO` except that it can be used to concatenate strings of text.  There is a good example in the `^FT` command section of the ZPL reference guide.